# How do I clean a silk tie at the knot?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, cleaning

I would like to know how I can clean a silk tie at the knot. I presume it got filthy, over time, due to "fatty" fingers. I am looking for answers either based on 1) good theory or 2) personal experience. I am *not* looking for grandma's advice.

Comment: I think this is fine for the site, it's an application question about materials and reagents.  You will probably get a better answer eventually.

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean by "at the knot"?

Comment: @qwersjc That's the location of the staining. The staining probably happens when I pull up the knot to my neck (over months or even years). Maybe it is sweat.